# Inverse lifting on applicative functors

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm pretty sure this has a simple solution but it eludes me and I cannot seem to find a straight answer.

Normally, when applying `liftA2` assuming the binary function has already been lifted once, the signature looks like this:

```
liftA2'   :: (Applicative f1, Applicative f) 
             => (f a -> f b -> f c) -> f1 (f a) -> f1 (f b) -> f1 (f c)
```

Is it possible to apply the "inverse" of, for example `liftA2` such as:

```
inverseA2 :: (Applicative f, Applicative f1) 
             => (f a -> f b -> f c) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b) -> f (f1 c)
```

---

As a concrete example, I would like to obtain the function:

```
f :: ([a] -> [b] -> [c]) -> [Maybe a] -> [Maybe b] -> [Maybe c]
```

One way would be to resort to "pack" each argument `[Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]` and "unpack" `Maybe [a] -> [Maybe a]` the result of applying a normal `liftA2`. I would like to avoid that since, as you can imagine, packing is destructive (e.g. `pack [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2] == Nothing` ).

---

**Update:** as @user2407038 pointed out, in order for `f` to apply the given function you necessarily need a function along the lines of `[Maybe a] -> [a]` which *does* lose information. So for these two particular functors there is no apparent way to satisfy the additional requirement posed. But for any other two functors `f`, `f1` which have an invertible function `forall a . f a -> f1 a` the answer accepted fits perfectly as a solution to this question.

Comment: Take `f :: [Int] -> [Char] -> [Int] ; f x y = [length x + length y]`. What would you expect from `inverseA2 f :: [Maybe Int] -> [Maybe Char] -> [Maybe Int]` ? What about `f x y = [length x + length y, head x]`? I'm not sure what the general definition would be...

Comment: In order for `f` to apply the given function, it must produce a `[a]` from a `[Maybe a]` (naturally there is no way to get `[a]` from `[Maybe b]` since there is no way to get `a` from `b`) and so you necessarily *need* a function `[Maybe a] -> [a]` - and as you've noted this function necessarily loses information. The same is true of the general case - there are few functors `f1, f2` which have an invertible function `forall a . f1 a -> f2 a`.

Comment: @user2407038 so there was a reason I did not find a straightforward answer, since I was looking at the wrong problem. Thanks for pointing out the invertible functions! I will look more into this.

Comment: @chi to clarify the situation with your example, let's say that I get the function `f` already defined as `f :: [Int] -> [Char] -> [Int]` and I would like to apply it to the respective structures `a = [Nothing, Just 1, Just 3]` and `b = [Just 'a', Just 'b']`. In this case the first function should return `inverseA2 f a b == [Just 5]`, while the second should be `inverseA2 f a b == [Just 5, Nothing]`. But using the pack/unpack method grants `[Nothing]` for the first function and `[Nothing]` for the second one respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've probably figured this out, but I don't think you can do this with the constraints you have. If you are a bit more liberal with your constraints, you'll get something though....

```
inverseA2 :: (Applicative f, Traversable f, Applicative f1, Traversable f1)
               => (f a -> f b -> f c) -> f (f1 a) -> f (f1 b) -> f (f1 c)
inverseA2 f x y = sequenceA (liftA2 f (sequenceA x) (sequenceA y))
```

The only reason I'm putting this up is that for your particular example with `Maybe` and `[]`, these constraints *are* all satisfied, so doing this is possible for that case. Still not settling at all though.

You could also try experimenting with writing your own instances for [`Data.Distributive`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.5.0.2/docs/Data-Distributive.html) giving you `distribute`, which is similar to `sequenceA`...

Edited to include @dfeuer's suggestions.

Comment: Very elegant! `sequence` describes perfectly what `pack` and `unpack` are doing, thanks for pointing it out (now I realized I am speaking gibberish when I talk about transposing, I will correct that)! Unfortunately, as you said, it is implementing the case I am trying to avoid. As in the example above, evaluating `inverseM2 (\x y = [length x + length y]) [Nothing, Just 1, Just 3] [Just 'a', Just 'b']` will return `[Nothing]` instead of `[Just 5]`

Comment: `Monad` is clearly overkill (just replace `sequence` with `sequenceA`). Also, I would speculate that you could use several combinations of `Traversable` and `Distributive` for context.

Comment: Although the resources you provide are invaluable, I still hit the problem of "sequencing" the input arguments (i.e. `[Maybe a] -> Maybe [a]`). For these two particular functors I cannot find such a non-destructive transformation, since there is no way of describing `Nothing` as a value in the set `a`. So I guess I should accept the situation as it is.